# Move div to another div with CSS and media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an odd situation where i need to move a div from one container to another using a media query - i don't even know if this can be done so bear with me.

I've created hexagonal shapes by skewing and rotating divs and these are then lined up one row at a time using negative margins (5 per row). This all works correctly, like so [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZcmZ/)

My issue is the responsive design, when the screen goes lower than 980px then i'd like to move the right hand most hexagons below.

Essentially at the moment i'm duplicating the div's so i can hide one and show the other (which works)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

div#hex14{display:block;}
div#hex0{display:none;}

div#hex14{display:block;}
div#hex0{display:none;}

}
```

However, there is dynamic content in the hexagons and i don't particularly want to duplicate all the content as well.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Create a JavaScript/jQuery function that will handle it?

Comment: Which is the route i originally went down (using enquire.js), but i couldn't get it working right. It's a lot more complex than you think.

Comment: Oh I can imagine! I'm impressed with what you've done so far - I'm one for making sites that have never been made in the same way before.